# ¿Cómo podría omitir tildes con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo varios `Array` con varios valores para generar una respuesta a las personas mediante un `input`. Por ejemplo, este `Array` luce así:

```js
var mil = [
  "SAN ANTONIO",
  "SAN MARTIN",
  "EL JARDIN",
  "EL CARMEN",
  "SAN ROQUE",
  "ARCO IRIS",
  "LA CRUZ",
  "SAN LUIS",
  "CASILDA MATAMOROS",
  "PEJE",
  "SAN PABLO",
  "SANTA FE"
];
```

Este `Array` es un conjunto de barrios o zonas donde el **dilevery** tiene un costo de mil y regresa este código en caso de que sea cierto:

```js
isInArray(mil, lastmsg) == true ? (smsg = ` Excelente tu barrio esta incluido en el costo de 1000;
```

Todo bien, pero si la persona ingresa una de las palabras del `Array` con tilde, se produce un error. No sé en realidad cómo hacer para que la tilde sea ignorada.

Comment: Angelo, que tal, al parecer no es la primera vez que usas S.O. en español... Si has leído [ask] y [tour] estarás consciente que tu "pregunta" carece de calidad y tu ejemplo no es claro y concreto para llevarnos a un contexto más puntual para poder ayudarte. En ese sentido sería bueno que mejores tu pregunta en base a esos 2 enlaces mencionados anteriormente para no obtener más puntuaciones negativas o reportes.

Comment: Creo que ya lo corregí, saludos

Answer (score 0):

hola quizas te sirva esta información segun entiendo buscas en tu arreglo,pero si esta con acento la palabra te marca un error, esto debe a que no la encuentra ya que mas != más , para omitir los acentos quizas te sirva esto https://desarrolloweb.com/faq/la-mejor-manera-de-eliminar-tildes-o-acentos-en-javascript